# Eliminating subst to prove equality

Tags: gadt, agda

I'm trying to representat mod-n counters as a cut of the interval `[0, ..., n-1]` into two parts:

```
data Counter : ℕ → Set where
  cut : (i j : ℕ) → Counter (suc (i + j))
```

Using this, defining the two crucial operations is straightforward (some proofs omitted for brevity):

```
_+1 : ∀ {n} → Counter n → Counter n
cut i zero    +1 = subst Counter {!!} (cut zero i)
cut i (suc j) +1 = subst Counter {!!} (cut (suc i) j)

_-1 : ∀ {n} → Counter n → Counter n
cut zero    j -1 = subst Counter {!!} (cut j zero)
cut (suc i) j -1 = subst Counter {!!} (cut i (suc j))
```

The problem comes when trying to prove that `+1` and `-1` are inverses. I keep running into situations where I need an eliminator for these `subst`s introduced, i.e. something like

```
subst-elim : {A : Set} → {B : A → Set} → {x x′ : A} → {x=x′ : x ≡ x′} → {y : B x} → subst B x=x′ y ≡ y
subst-elim {A} {B} {x} {.x} {refl} = refl
```

but this turns out to be (somewhat) begging the question: it isn't accepted by the type checker, because `subst B x=x' y : B x'` and `y : B x`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can state the type of your subst-elim if you use Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality from the stdlib.
However i'd probably just pattern match on the eventual proof of x ≡ x′ in a with or rewrite clause, so you don't have to make an explicit eliminator and so no typing problem.

Comment: HeterogenousEquality feels like the right solution to this problem... However, I get a somewhat similar problem when trying to use that: I can't define something like `Counter-cong : ∀ {n n′} {A : ℕ → Set} → (f : ∀{n} → Counter n → A n) → {k : Counter n} {k′ : Counter n′} → k ≅ k′ → f k ≅ f k′`, because then I get the `Refuse to solve heterogeneous constraint k : Counter n =?= k′ :
Counter n′` error message...