# Stuck on proof with heterogeneous equality

Tags: agda

I have a binary number representation, plus some conversion to and from Nat:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality hiding (trans; cong; subst; sym)
open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality
open import Data.Unit
open import Algebra
module CS = CommutativeSemiring commutativeSemiring 

data Bin : ℕ → Set where
  zero  : Bin zero
  2*n   : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (n + n)
  2*n+1 : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (suc (n + n))

suc-lem : ∀ n → suc (suc (n + n)) ≡ suc n + suc n
suc-lem zero = refl
suc-lem (suc n) rewrite 
    CS.+-comm n (suc n)
  | suc-lem n | CS.+-comm n (suc (suc n)) 
  | CS.+-comm n (suc n) = refl

inc : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (suc n)
inc zero = 2*n+1 zero
inc (2*n b) = 2*n+1 b
inc (2*n+1 {n} b) rewrite suc-lem n = 2*n (inc b)

nat2bin : (n : ℕ) → Bin n
nat2bin zero = zero
nat2bin (suc n) = inc (nat2bin n)

bin2nat : ∀ {n} → Bin n → ℕ
bin2nat {n} b = n
```

I think I need heterogeneous equality for proving things here, since it's usually not evident that the Nat indices of two Bin-s are equal. I'm rather inexperienced in Agda though, so please tell me if the approach is misguided.

I'm stuck with the following:

```
lem : ∀ n → 2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n)) ≅ inc (inc (2*n+1 (nat2bin n)))
lem zero = refl
lem (suc n) = 
  subst
    (λ b → 2*n+1 (inc (inc (nat2bin n))) ≅ inc (inc b))
    (sym $ lem ?) ?
```

The obvious thing would be to plug in `n` into `sym $ lem ?`, but that results in an error complaining that `suc (n + n) != n + suc n`.

I'd like to know why this happens or how it could be helped.

Comment: I am wondering about the use of the `Bin` data type rather than say `Data.Bin.Bin` from the standard library. Also why does it allow infinitely many representations of `zero`? Maybe you want `2*n : ∀ {n} → Bin (suc n) → Bin (suc n + suc n)`?

Comment: @Helmut I copied (sort of) the datatype from the Software Foundations book. It has infinitely many zeros so that we can practice proving things about normalizing away the needless constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imports:

```
open import Level hiding (zero; suc)
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality
  renaming (sym to hsym; trans to htrans; cong to hcong; subst to hsubst)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Fin hiding (_+_)
open import Algebra
open import Data.Nat.Properties
module ℕplus = CommutativeSemiring commutativeSemiring
```

I've rearranged your `inc` a little to simplify things:

```
inc : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (suc n)
inc zero = 2*n+1 zero
inc (2*n b) = 2*n+1 b
inc (2*n+1 {n} b) = subst (Bin ∘ suc) (ℕplus.+-comm n (suc n)) (2*n (inc b))
```

Lemma:

```
lem : ∀ n → 2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n)) ≅ inc (inc (2*n+1 (nat2bin n)))
lem zero = refl
lem (suc n) = {!!}
```

The type of the hole is

```
2*n+1 (inc (inc (nat2bin n))) ≅
      inc
      (subst ((λ {.x} → Bin) ∘ suc) (ℕplus.+-comm (suc n) (suc (suc n)))
       (2*n (inc (inc (nat2bin n)))))
```

So we need something like subst-removable from the standart library:

```
≡-subst-removable : ∀ {a p} {A : Set a}
                    (P : A → Set p) {x y} (eq : x ≡ y) z →
                    P.subst P eq z ≅ z
≡-subst-removable P refl z = refl
```

The type of

```
hsym $
  ≡-subst-removable
    (Bin ∘ suc)
    (ℕplus.+-comm (suc n) (suc (suc n)))
    (2*n $ inc $ inc $ nat2bin n)
```

is

```
(2*n $ inc $ inc $ nat2bin n) ≅
      subst ((λ {.x} → Bin) ∘ suc) (ℕplus.+-comm (suc n) (suc (suc n)))
      (2*n $ inc $ inc $ nat2bin n)
```

Almost what we need. Now we want to add `hcong inc`, but compiler rejects it.
Here is the implementation of `cong`:

```
cong : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} {x y}
       (f : (x : A) → B x) → x ≅ y → f x ≅ f y
cong f refl = refl
```

So `x` and `y` must be of the same type `A`, while our `subst` changes the type.
Here is the implementation of `hcong`, that we need:

```
hcong' : {α β γ : Level} {I : Set α} {i j : I}
       -> (A : I -> Set β) {B : {k : I} -> A k -> Set γ} {x : A i} {y : A j}
       -> i ≡ j
       -> (f : {k : I} -> (x : A k) -> B x)
       -> x ≅ y
       -> f x ≅ f y
hcong' _ refl _ refl = refl
```

And the final proof:

```
lem : ∀ n → 2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n)) ≅ inc (inc (2*n+1 (nat2bin n)))
lem zero = refl
lem (suc n) =
  hcong'
    (Bin ∘ suc)
    (ℕplus.+-comm (suc n) (suc (suc n)))
    inc
    $ hsym
      $ ≡-subst-removable
          (Bin ∘ suc)
          (ℕplus.+-comm (suc n) (suc (suc n)))
          (2*n $ inc $ inc $ nat2bin n)
```

Also, we can consolidate `subst-removable` and `cong`:

```
≡-cong-subst-removable : {α β γ : Level} {I : Set α} {i j : I}
                       -> (A : I -> Set β) {B : {k : I} -> A k -> Set γ}
                       -> (e : i ≡ j)
                       -> (x : A i)
                       -> (f : {k : I} -> (x : A k) -> B x)
                       -> f (subst A e x) ≅ f x
≡-cong-subst-removable _ refl _ _ = refl

lem' : ∀ n → 2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n)) ≅ inc (inc (2*n+1 (nat2bin n)))
lem' zero = refl
lem' (suc n) = hsym $
  ≡-cong-subst-removable
    (Bin ∘ suc)
    (ℕplus.+-comm (suc n) (suc (suc n)))
    (2*n $ inc $ inc $ nat2bin n)
    inc
```

BTW, Pierce meant this datatype, I suppose:

```
data Bin : Set where
  zero  : Bin
  2*n   : Bin → Bin
  2*n+1 : Bin → Bin
```

BTW2, it's possible to prove your contrived-example without additional definitions:

```
contrived-example : {n : ℕ} {f : Fin (n + suc n)}
                  -> f ≅ fromℕ (n + suc n)
                  -> f ≅ fromℕ (suc n + n)
contrived-example {n} eq = htrans eq $ hcong fromℕ $ ≡-to-≅ $ ℕplus.+-comm n (suc n)
```

BTW3, hsubst-ix1 can be reduced a lot, since you use heterogeneous equality and do not need to prove equality of types:

```
hsubst' : {C1 C2 : Set} {x : C1} {y : C2}
        -> (P : {C : Set} -> C -> Set)
        -> x ≅ y
        -> P x
        -> P y
hsubst' _ refl x = x

contrived-example' : 
  ∀ n
  → (f : Fin (n + suc n)) 
  → (fromℕ (n + suc n) ≅ fromℕ (suc n + n))
  → (f ≅ fromℕ (n + suc n))
  → (f ≅ fromℕ (suc n + n)) 
contrived-example' n f eq p = hsubst' (λ f' → f ≅ f') eq p
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of expert answer I looked for.

Comment: Also, I can see how defining `inc` in terms of `subst` is very useful, but I'm curious how `lem` could be proved with my original `rewrite` definition of `inc`.

Comment: Not necessarily the original one, because I see now that `suc-lem` is unnecessary, but for example one with `inc (2*n+1 {n} b) with 2*n $ inc b
... | b' rewrite ℕsr.+-comm n (suc n) = b'`

Comment: In other words: how can I undo `rewrite` similarly to how I can undo `subst`?

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498428/types-containing-with-rewrite-clauses-in-agda-or-how-to-use-rewrite-instead-of But something went wrong with this machinery in my code: http://lpaste.net/105750

Comment: It looks like version 0.16 of the standard library will include `icong` and `icong-≡-subst-removable` that have similar definitions to your `hcong'` and `≡-cong-subst-removable`. I would suggest to use the versions from the standard library instead of making them by yourself (although it is a very nice learning experience).

Comment: @DrPhil, I [suggest](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2016/009069.html) not to use heterogeneous equality at all.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this problem is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310520/congruence-for-heterogenous-equality), except that here injective type constructors don't help.

Normally you can use the `subst` for heterogeneous equality when it is evident that the two types on the sides of the equality are equal:

```
hsubst :
  {A    : Set}
  (P    : A → Set)
  {x x' : A}
  → x ≅ x'
  → P x
  → P x' 
hsubst P refl p = p
```

This `hsubst` is pretty much the same as `subst` for propositional equality, except for the type of the equality. Since we are required to know that the types of `x` and `x'` are equal, we could have just converted our heterogeneous equality proof into a normal one, and then used the regular `subst`.

However, OP (i. e. me) tried to substitute using an equality that had indexed types on both sides, and it was not evident that the indices were equal. The solution is to parametrize `hsubst` by the index and demand an additional equality proof for the indices:

```
hsubst-ix1 : 
    {I    : Set}
    (C    : I → Set)  
    (P    : ∀ {i} → C i → Set)
    {i i' : I}
    {x    : C i}
    {x'   : C i'}
    → i ≡ i'
    → x ≅ x'
    → P x
    → P x'
hsubst-ix1 C P refl refl p = p
```

I experimented a bit to find out which arguments can be left to be inferred, and the result is above. Here's a contrived example:

```
open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality hiding (cong)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Fin hiding (_+_)
open import Algebra
open import Data.Nat.Properties
module ℕplus = CommutativeSemiring commutativeSemiring

contrived-example : 
  ∀ n
  → (f : Fin (n + suc n)) 
  → (fromℕ (n + suc n) ≅ fromℕ (suc n + n))
  → (f ≅ fromℕ (n + suc n))
  → (f ≅ fromℕ (suc n + n)) 
contrived-example n f eq p =
  hsubst-ix1
    -- the type constructor to be indexed
    Fin
    -- substitution
    (λ f' → f ≅ f')
    -- proof that the indices are equal
    (cong suc (ℕplus.+-comm n (suc n)))
    -- heterogeneous equality
    eq
    -- original expression
    p
```